# Can't connect to a game over remote LAN

Tags: networking, port, gaming

First of all I want to say that I'm not entirely sure if this question can be asked here. If it can't, then please tell me and I will delete it.

There's this game called Killing Floor, which can be played Co-op over LAN. I'm hosting the game, and we downloaded Hamachi to emulate the LAN connection. But one of my friends is not able to connect at all. I think it could be a ports problem, but unfortunately his router doesn't provide port forwarding features in its software. How can we troubleshoot this or workaround the issue?

The ports needed are:
    7707 UDP/IP (Game Port)
    7708 UDP/IP (Query Port)
    7717 UDP/IP (GameSpy Query Port)
    28852 TCP/IP and UDP (Allows your Server to Connect to the Master Server Browser)

Is there a way to troubleshoot a connection to see if it really is a ports problem? Or to force it? Maybe another way to connect more freely? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you all have Hamachi then the router is irrelevant, since it's as if your all on the same LAN. What about firewalls? try shutting it down and how it goes.